# igraph layout.fruchterman.reingold outliers (example image included)

Tags: r, igraph

Sometimes when using a layout algorithm such as layout.fruchterman.reingold you can get some nodes that are outliers in the sense that they extend out disproportionately from the rest of the structure. Does anyone know how to impose a maximum length on edges (such as =1) so that the edge cannot exceed a max length and therefore remove these outliers?

```
l <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(subgraph)
```

BTW, I'm aware of an employ a scale factor already to regin things in:

```
l <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(subgraph) * scaleFactor
```

[image: Example of Outliers]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality for that in the Fruchterman-Reingold algorithm (and I suspect that using `xmin`, `ymin`, `xmax` and `ymax` would not work because it might simply "compress" the non-outlier part of the network to make more space for the outliers), but you can probably experiment with edge weights. When the FR layout algorithm is used with weights, the algorithm will strive to make edges with a larger weight to be shorter. You could probably try setting the weights incident on "outlier" vertices (i.e. vertices with degree=1 or 2) to a smaller value. Another possibility is to make the edge weights depend on the degrees of both endpoints such that smaller degrees are mapped to smaller values but larger degrees are *not* mapped to disproportionately larger values - maybe the geometric mean of the degrees of the two endpoints could be useful here. But there is no "universal" solution as far as I know so you'll have to experiment a bit.

Answer (score -1):

When asking a question with an example that is dependent on non-base functions, please remember to note which package they live in.

(for those wondering, it's in igraph).

igraph's documentation for the fruchterman-reingold layout method contains, in "arguments":

> **xmin,xmax**
>
> The limits for the first coordinate, if one of them or both are NULL then no     normalization is performed along this direction.
>
> **ymin,ymax**
>
> The limits for the second coordinate, if one of them or both are NULL then no normalization is performed along this direction.
>
> **zmin,zmax**
>
> The limits for the third coordinate, if one of them or both are NULL then no normalization is performed along this direction.

...so, set limits on x and y? Z isn't necessary unless it's a three-dimensional graph.